# ggplot2: highlight chart area

Tags: r, ggplot2, xts, quantmod

I am working with some time series data and would like to highlight chart area whenever certain conditions become true. For example:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(quantmod)
initDate <- "1993-01-31"
endDate <- "2012-08-10"
symbols <- c("SPY")
getSymbols(symbols, from=initDate, to=endDate, index.class=c("POSIXt","POSIXct"))
spy<-SPY$SPY.Adjusted
spy$sma<-SMA(spy$SPY.Adjusted,200)
spy<-spy[-(1:199),] 
spy<-as.data.frame(spy)
ggplot(spy,aes(x=index(spy),y=spy$SPY.Adjusted))+geom_line()+geom_line(aes(x=index(spy),y=spy$sma))
```

The above code plots the the data, but how can I highlight the section when ever close is above sma? This question is similar to [How to highlight time ranges on a plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733182/how-to-highlight-time-ranges-on-a-plot), but then it is manual. Is there a function in ggplot2 for conditional plotting?

Comment: The question you link to _is_ the way to do this. **ggplot2** does not yet have the functionality to understand something like `geom_shade_the_region_that_I_have_in_mind_you_know_that_one()`. You have to actually tell it what region you want shaded.

Comment: You would increase your chances of getting non-quants to experiment with your code if you put in proper library calls to indicate which packages are needed to run that code.

Comment: @joran thanks so much for the insightful answer~ will work hard to come up with something useful.

Comment: I should add, though, that it's certainly possible to use the technique in the linked question to write a function that returns the desired `geom_rect` object. But you still have to write that function yourself, 'by hand'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on code in the [TA.R](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/R/TA.R?view=markup&root=quantmod) file of the [quantmod](http://cran.r-project.org/package=quantmod) package, here is code that uses `rle` to find the starts and ends of the rectangles.

```
runs <- rle(as.logical(spy[, 1] > spy[, 2]))
l <- list(start=cumsum(runs$length)[which(runs$values)] - runs$length[which(runs$values)] + 1,
          end=cumsum(runs$lengths)[which(runs$values)])
rect <- data.frame(xmin=l$start, xmax=l$end, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf)
```

Combine that with some `ggplot2` code from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4733446/967840) to the question you linked to:

```
ggplot(spy,aes(x=index(spy),y=spy$SPY.Adjusted))+geom_line()+geom_line(aes(x=index(spy),y=spy$sma))+geom_rect(data=rect, aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), color="grey20", alpha=0.5, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

And you get:

[image]

If you reverse the order of plotting and use `alpha=1` in `geom_rect` it may (or may not) look more like you desire:

```
ggplot(spy,aes(x=index(spy),y=spy$SPY.Adjusted))+geom_rect(data=rect, aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), border=NA, color="grey20", alpha=1, inherit.aes = FALSE)+geom_line()+geom_line(aes(x=index(spy),y=spy$sma))
```

[image]

---

Since you have an `xts` object. You may not even want to convert to a `data.frame`.  Here is how you could plot it using the brand new `plot.xts` method in the [xtsExtra](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/xtsExtra/?root=xts) package created by Michael Weylandt as part of a Google Summer of Code [project.](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=developers:projects:gsoc2012:xts)

```
spy <- as.xts(spy)
require(xtsExtra)
plot(spy, screens=1,
     blocks=list(start.time=paste(index(spy)[l$start]),
                 end.time=paste(index(spy)[l$end]), col='lightblue'),                    
     legend.loc='bottomright', auto.legend=TRUE)
```

[image]