# Highlight plot area in time series

Tags: r, plot, xts

I have plotted my xts time series as following:

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
prices <- as.xts(sample_matrix)[,"Close"]
pw_returns <- diff(log(prices))
plot(pw_returns, main="", col="darkblue", lwd=1)
```

I would like to highlight volatility clusters as it has been done in the following graph:

[image]

someone knows how to do it in R?

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133846/ggplot2-highlight-chart-area?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot2: highlight chart area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133846/ggplot2-highlight-chart-area)

Comment: @RobertoMoratore; not sure if this graphic here is `ggplot2`.

Comment: Also, @toyo10, please provide a minimal reproducible example. We don't have the `pw_returns` object.

Comment: @Axeman, the question was about doing in R and not specifically in base plot. I think the link above still applies.

Comment: I didn't post the return series since doesn't matter. The question was if I have a general return series. Can I do it without using `ggplot2`??

Comment: @toyo10: It's courteous to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/271616) to make it easier to answer your question. That's easy for you to do with the data the comes with xts: `data(sample_matrix, package = "xts")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `addPolygon()`.  It will help to create an intermediate object containing the upper and lower bounds of the shaded region.

```
nr <- nrow(pw_returns)
shade <- cbind(upper = rep(1, nr), lower = rep(-1, nr))
shade <- xts(shade, index(pw_returns))
```

Now we can plot and add a shaded region for any period we want. Make sure to set `on = -1` to draw the shaded region *behind* the main plot.

```
# main plot
plot(pw_returns, main = "", col = "darkblue", lwd = 1)
# add shaded region to February, 2007
addPolygon(shade["2007-02"], col = "lightpink", on = -1)
```

[image: xts plot with shaded region]