# Looking for R code to sum a variable across rows based off a range of possible values contained within the same row

Tags: r, sum, weather, noaa

I'm working with a simple dataset. It contains three variables of interest. 1. Date YYYY-MM-DD 2. Hourly (##) 3. Precip_H (#.##).

My situation is that I am trying to find code that will for example, sum the precip_H values across rows that are equal to a specific DATE and are within 00-11 for the value of Hourly. Then the next set would do all the same but for 12-23 range in Hourly.

This dataset is a weather station that reports precipitation hourly. What I am trying to do is use that information to make two 12 hour precipitation values per day across all days of the dataset.

```
   DATE       TIME  PRECIP_H DATEyyyy DATEmm DATEdd
   <date>     <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 2019-06-05 17           0     2019      6      5
 2 2019-06-01 20           0     2019      6      1
 3 2019-06-06 19           0     2019      6      6
 4 2019-05-27 00           0     2019      5     27
 5 2019-08-25 20           0     2019      8     25
 6 2019-08-08 04           0     2019      8      8
 7 2019-09-01 07           0     2019      9      1
 8 2019-07-18 21           0     2019      7     18
 9 2019-06-18 23           0     2019      6     18
10 2019-08-11 12           0     2019      8     11

library(readxl)
precip2019 <- Clean_Chicago_Midway_Precp_Hourly_2019_1945790 <- read_excel("S:/Natural Resources/Staff/Beach Management/Beaches Main/+ DATA ANALYSIS +/Beaches 2019/Master Files/Clean_Chicago Midway Precp Hourly 2019_1945790.xlsx")


names(precip2019)[names(precip2019) == "HourlyPrecipitation"] <- "PRECIP_H"


precip2019$DATE <- as.Date(precip2019$DATE, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
precip2019$DATEyyyy <- as.numeric(format(precip2019$DATE, '%Y'))
precip2019$DATEmm <- as.numeric(format(precip2019$DATE, '%m'))
precip2019$DATEdd <- as.numeric(format(precip2019$DATE, '%d'))

prec_sum <- precip2019 %>% 
  select(DATE, TIME, starts_with("PREC")) %>% 
  mutate(Period = case_when(between(TIME, 0, 11) ~ "1st_half",
                            TRUE ~ "2nd_half")) %>% 
  group_by(DATE, Period) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("PREC")), list(~ sum(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
  ungroup()
View(prec_sum)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read this and try to make your problem reproducible so others can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

This might work for your case. First we need to create a `Period` column based on the time range (`case_when`). Then do the summation based on a group of two columns `DATE` and `Period` (`summarise_at`).

```
library(dplyr)

prec_sum <- prec_data %>% 
  select(DATE, TIME, starts_with("PREC")) %>% 
  mutate(TIME = as.numeric(TIME)) %>% 
  mutate(Period = case_when(between(TIME, 0, 11) ~ "1st_half",
                            TRUE ~ "2nd_half")) %>% 
  group_by(DATE, Period) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("PREC")), list(~ sum(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: I'm getting this error : 
Error: Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double].

I've only modified to include the dataset name:
prec_sum <- precip2019 %>% 
  select(DATE, TIME, starts_with("PREC")) %>% 
  mutate(Period = case_when(between(TIME, 0, 11) ~ "1st_half",
                            TRUE ~ "2nd_half")) %>% 
  group_by(DATE, Period) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("PREC")), list(~ sum(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
  ungroup()

Comment: Please post the sample of your dataset per the instruction in the link I posted. It's closet to impossible to know why error happened without seeing the data

Comment: Have a look now

Comment: Better but not yet reproducible. See this example https://stackoverflow.com/q/56811184/786542. Make sure that others can copy and paste the code then run it on a different computer.