# R Plotly, composite scatter graph

Tags: r, plotly, scatter-plot, r-plotly

I have a data set which contains three columns: `Date` with no time stamp, `TimeTS` of the day converted to number of hours since midnight for a specific event associated with the `Date`. The third column is the `Phase` which is either or `morning`, `afternoon`, `evening` or `night`. Phase is derived from `TimeTS`.

Below is a sample

```
Date       TimeTS   Phase  
2020-01-29 2.75     Night 
2020-01-29 4.83     Morning
2020-01-29 7        Morning
2020-01-30 10.6     Afternoon
```

I need to use an interactive charting like `plotly` to show the following:

- A scatter chart with `Date` on the x-axis and `Time`on the `y` with each instance of time marked across each date
- Translucent bands of the `Phase` running horizontally on the chart for easy interpretation of time bands and the distribution of markers by `Phase`

The below code gives me close to my desired result but not exactly.

```
p <- ggplot(clean.data, aes(x=Date,y=TimeTS)) +
  geom_rect(data=clean.data, mapping = aes(
    xmin=min(Date),
    xmax=max(Date),
    ymin=0,
    ymax=24,
    fill=Phase), alpha=0.1) +
  # scale_fill_manual(values=c("Morning" = "red", "Afternoon" = "blue", "Evening" = "green", "Night" = "black")) +
  geom_point()
p <- ggplotly(p)
p
```

This gets me only one of the `Phase` bands on the chart and not others. Plus i think its running vertically and not horizontally.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: You need to create a separate data.frame for the rectangles and define their start and end points. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543176/highlight-areas-within-certain-x-range-in-ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543176/highlight-areas-within-certain-x-range-in-ggplot2) for a (partial) solution for your problem.

Comment: @user12728748, thx mate. I will try this tomorrow and let you know, how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user12728748, I was able to get this done. Code changes below:

```
df.phase <- data.frame(start = c(0,4,10,16,22), end = c(4,10,16,22,24), phase = c("Night", "Morning", "Afternoon", "Evening", "Night"))

p <- ggplot(clean.data, aes(x=Date,y=TimeTS)) +
  geom_rect(data=df.phase, inherit.aes = FALSE, aes(
    xmin= min(clean.data$Date),
    xmax= max(clean.data$Date),
    ymin=start,
    ymax=end,
    fill=phase), alpha=0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Morning" = "orange", "Afternoon" = "blue", "Evening" = "pink", "Night" = "black")) +
  geom_point()
p <- ggplotly(p)
p
```

The code will generate the following output
[image: Horizontal Rectangular swimlanes on a scatter plot]