# How to highlight a specific area of a bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, highlight, geom-bar

I have this set of discrete data (O.D.) which are referred to some of my samples:

```
SAMPLE     O.D.600nm
I (D+G)       0.3
II (D+G)      0.3
III (D+G)     0.28
VII (YPD)     0.4
VIII(YPD)     0.42
IX (YPD)      0.388
```

And I made a pretty basic Bar chart out of it using the following `ggplot` code:

```
ggplot(myData, aes(SAMPLE, O.D.600nm, fill=SAMPLE)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("lightblue", "lightblue", "lightblue", "orange", "orange", "orange"))+
  geom_text(aes(label=O.D.600nm),position="stack",vjust=1)+
  ylim(0,0.625)
```

This is my result:

[image]

So, my question is the following: is it possible to highlight/colour the whole area of the chart that goes from the O.D. 0.3 to the O.D. 0.6?

Comment: Do you mean the background area?

Comment: See [`annotate`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotate.html) for some examples, including a rectangle one. Basically you want something like `+ annotate('rect', xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = 3, ymax = 6,
  alpha = .2)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to highlight time ranges on a plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733182/how-to-highlight-time-ranges-on-a-plot)

Comment: @Axeman Yes!! Thank you so much, that was exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw multiple squares with ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903868/draw-multiple-squares-with-ggplot)